Testcafe 3+ throws 'Uncaught Object was thrown. ...Throw error instead.' using typeText on a field that already has text
We use Testcafe for frontend test automation on a Vue app. After upgrading to version 3.6 from 2.6.1, the typeText method throws an obscure error when typing text into a field that is auto-populated with text (in this case, a reply button is clicked which shows a text field with a username mention pre-populated, and attempting to add more text causes this error). The issue happens on Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. The error says something about an iFrame, but there is no iFrame related to these components or on the page where this test is failing.
text field from the Vue source code:
<template>
  <div
    ref="contentEditable"
    role="textbox"
    contenteditable="true"
    aria-multiline="true"
    @input="contentEditableEventHandler"
    @blur="onBlur"
  />
</template>

Selector definition in Testcafe:
this.replyForm = Selector('form.content-reply-form');
this.replyInput = this.replyForm.find('div.mention-box__input');

Helper function which fails on the typeText line:
async setReply(replyText) {
    await t.expect(this.replyInput.visible).ok();
    // await t.click(this.replyInput);
    // console.log(await this.replyInput.innerText);
    // await t.pressKey('right');
    await t.typeText(this.replyInput, replyText, { paste: true });
  }

Error in console:
1) Uncaught object

   "{"callsite":{"filename":"/Users/anthony.ferro/Developer/nexus-e2e/pages/moderation/flagDetailPage.js","lineNum":254,"callsiteFrameIdx":5,"stackFrames":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],"isV8Frames":true}}"
      was thrown. Throw Error instead.

      Browser: Chrome 125.0.0.0 / Ventura 13

No error occurs with all of the above when there is no previous text (username mention) present. See the following screenshots of the DOM:
Chrome>>dom_screenshot_chrome
When the div[role=textbox] here does not have the nested span tag, no errors occur. Once it does, typeText and pressKey both throw the above error.
Tried running the test with and without native automation enabled for Chrome, with no difference. The issue also happens in Firefox, which suggests it has nothing to do with the new chrome/native automation changes in Testcafe. The issue does not happen in Safari despite the DOM being similar. See screenshots:
safari>> dom_screenshot_safari
where there is no issue
firefox>> dom_screenshot_firefox
where the issue still happens
Tried adding await t.expect(this.replyInput.visible).ok(); before typeText - made no difference. Also confirmed in the TC debugger that my selector for this field is valid + no others found that it could be confused with.
Tried explicitly clicking the input although it appears to be focused already - this doesn't throw the error, but instead proceeds without entering any text, making the test fail.
Tried adding await t.pressKey('right'); before typeText - the same error is thrown on the pressKey line instead.
Tried console.log(await this.replyInput.innerText); before typeText - this correctly outputs the existing text in the input (the username mention text).
Tried upgrading Node from v18.14.0 to v20.14.0 - issue still occurs.
Tried typeText with and without { paste: true } for all these scenarios - made no difference.
Tried moving the helper function code into a try/catch - still caught the same error message.
One last screenshot for what the test looks like when it fails. The runner will flash green a bunch of times like it's doing things, then turns red when it fails:
runner_screenshot
Usually I'd try to log this issue in the Testcafe repo, but their team doesn't dig into issues unless you provide your source code, which I can't give to them. So here is my first ever Stack Overflow post ;) Any fixes, workarounds, others who have seen this or advice is greatly appreciated. Similar issues I've found are either from many years/TC versions ago, or are about interacting with iFrames, which I am not.
